# How can I determine at runtime if a read-only property is weak?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have a class that declares two properties.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id first;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id second;
```

I use the following code at runtime to check the attributes of the properties:

```
unsigned int propertyCount;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &propertyCount);
for (int propertyIndex = 0; propertyIndex < propertyCount; propertyIndex++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[propertyIndex];
    const char *rawName = property_getName(property);
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:rawName encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    BOOL isWeak = [self propertyIsWeak:property];
    char const *attributes = property_getAttributes(property);
    NSString *attributesString = [NSString stringWithCString:attributes encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    NSArray *attributesArray = [attributesString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    BOOL weak = [attributesArray containsObject:@"W"];
    NSLog(@"attributes of property are %@.  Weak? %d", attributesString, weak);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get these results:

```
attributes of property are T@,R,N,V_first.  Weak? 0
attributes of property are T@,W,N,V_second.  Weak? 1
```

Clearly from the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objcruntimeguide/articles/ocrtpropertyintrospection.html the first property should have a 'W' also, but it doesn't.  Does anyone know how to detect that this property is actually weak?

Note that it really does matter that it is declared as weak, the compiler cares and treats it appropriately.

This seems like a bug, but I still need a method that actually works.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why do you need to determine this at runtime? Why is this important for you to be able to check?

Comment: I think W here stands for write, i mean read and write. not weak

Comment: @santhu Visit the link, and you'll see that W stands for weak. And @MicahHainline I'm guessing this is telling you that maybe you can't have a property that is readonly and weak. Check out the assembly for property `first` and see if there is any difference in the code with or without `weak`.

Comment: @Gavin, I'm writing a runtime verification of something that needs to be invariant across the codebase.  Namely that certain types of classes do not hold strong pointers to certain other classes.  Automated testing basically.

Comment: Sounds like a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1):

By setting it as readonly simply means you're not creating a setter method. So setting it as weak, is counter intuitive. The strong/weak modifier doesn't make any difference to a readonly property other than changing the lifetime qualifier of the synthesized ivar

I would set it as Readonly in the .h and then if you want it to be a weak variable inside the .m file have

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id first
```

This way it's readonly externally but weak internal if that is what you want.

Comment: I'm not interested in what the property should be declared as.  I'm only interested in detecting what it IS.

Comment: Why? i.e. what are trying to achieve by determining that? My original point is that you wouldn't declare something readonly, weak. So by doing that you're confusing the issue hence why you're getting un expected results. After all the instance it's pointing at would have to be strong some where in order to exist.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve by determining that is runtime verification of an invariant in some code for unit testing purposes.  And people ARE creating (readonly, weak) properties, and it DOES change the runtime behavior of the app when they're weak vs not.

Comment: The fact people are marking things readonly, weak is interesting if for the reasons above not how you should do it. I'd fix the code, ask whom ever is writing it WTF? and worry less about testing for bad code IMO